# misuse of aggregate function SUM()

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to insert the SUM of `Somme_versee` (column in table `Versement`) in the column `Versement_total`.
This is a part of my  code:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Versement ( Nom , Prenom, Date , Somme_versee,Prix_du_logement, Nom_du_projet) VALUES('" + nom.getText() +"','" +prenom.getText() +"','"  +date.getText() + "'," +  verse.getText() + ", " + "(SELECT Prix_du_logement FROM Client WHERE Nom='"+ nom.getText() +"' AND Prenom='"+ prenom.getText() + "')," + " (SELECT  Nom_du_projet  FROM Client WHERE Nom='" + nom.getText()+ "' AND Prenom='" +prenom.getText() + "'))");
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE Versement SET Versement_total= SUM(Somme_versee) " );
```

When executing I get this error: `misuse of aggregate function SUM()`

Comment: Design seems incorrect. How can one column holding X and another holding sum(X) be at the same level ? Sum yields a single value.

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: my goal is too add new Somme_versee (Amount paid)   then calculate the sum of all Somme_versee (amount paid).

Answer (score 0):

You should never do this in the same table. And it will get worse when the table gets more records. But what you seem to want is:

```
UPDATE Versement SET Versement_total = (SELECT SUM(Somme_versee) FROM Versement)
```